# Vim: How to use unix command output as a filename to save to?

Tags: vim, command

I want to use unix command on save. Command return file path. Like below:

```
pseudo code
:w !command

# I name this command 'mami'
$ MAMI_DIR=~/work echo $MAMI_DIR/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").txt
#=> /Users/sane/work/2012-09-13-01-58-01.txt
```

https://gist.github.com/3713132

```
# my expectation
:w !mami
#=> to save /Users/sane/work/2012-09-13-01-58-01.txt
# or
:mami
#=> to save /Users/sane/work/2012-09-13-01-58-01.txt
```

But my exec is only return string or errors:

```
:w !mami
#=> This show only file path, /Users/sane/work/2012-09-13-01-58-01.txt and said "press key"
:w !$(MAMI_DIR=~/work echo $MAMI_DIR/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").txt)
#=> This return value 127
```

How do I achieve this? Is this the area of vim script? Please give me suggestion.

Comment: What you were requesting with the title (before I fixed it) is `autocmd BufWritePost {pattern} !mami`: running command after you save file, not running command to get filename to save to. Be careful with wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
:w `mami`
```

to achieve what you want. What you were actually doing was piping output to the `mami` command.

Comment: I want separate solutions to get filename to save to, and actually save file, so this is better. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `mami` do it:

```
MAMI_DIR=~/work cat >$MAMI_DIR/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").txt
```

and then `w !mami`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with backticks:

```
:w `mami`
```